# How to avoid circular dependency from abstracting navigation in desktop application?

Tags: java, architecture, mvvm, circular-dependency, javafx

I am trying to abstract some functionality from my desktop application (JavaFX) for changing views.

So, what I am thinking is:

Navigator interface with methods like `goToAccountsOverview()`, `goToAccountDetails(Account account)` etc. The implementation will depend on a `ViewFactory` to create the Views and a `DisplayingViewChanger` to change the view that is being displayed.

There will be multiple navigator interfaces depending on the state of the application, starting with:

- `NotConnectedStateNavigator` (`goToConnectToDatabase()`, `goToCreateDatabase()` etc)
- `ConnectedStateNavigator` (`goToAccountsOverview()`, `goToAccountDetails(Account account)` etc)

So each state will have its own navigator and view factory and a common view changer. The view factories and navigators will not share a common interface (`createView(ViewEnum v)` and `goToView(View view)` respectively).

While implementing this I run into a problem. An example of the problem is this:

In the `AccountsOverviewView` there is a table with all the accounts. Each account has a button to view the details. Pressing that button should navigate to the `AccountDetailsView` with the ViewModel of the account (I am using some sort of MVVM).

To do that it would call `connectedStateNavigator.goToAccountDetails(accountVM)` which would call `viewChanger.changeView(connectedStateViewFactory.createAccountDetailsView(accountVM)`).

So the `AccountsOverviewView` needs the `ConnectedStateNavigator`, which needs the `ConnectedStateViewFactory`, which needs to be able to construct the original `AccountsOverviewView`, which needs the `ConnectedStateNavigator` etc.

Some code to explain it better:

```
public class AccountsOverviewView {
    public AccountsOverviewView(ConnectedStateNavigator navigator, ...) {
        (...)
        accountDetailsButton.onClick(e -> navigator.goToAccountDetails(account));
        (...)
    }
}

public class ConnectedStateNavigator {
    public ConnectedStateNavigator(ConnectedStateViewFactory viewFactory, ...) { ... }  

    public void goToAccountDetails(Account account) {
        viewChanger.changeView(viewFactory.createAccountDetailsView(account));
    }
}

public class ConnectedStateViewFactory {
    public ConnectedStateViewFactory(ConnectedStateNavigator navigator, ...) { ... }

    public View createAccountsOverviewView() {
        return new AccountsOverviewView(new AccountsOverviewViewModel(navigator, ...));
    }

    public View createAccountDetailsView(Account account) { ... }
}
```

How could I design this better to avoid this cyclic reference?
Is using a setter or an asynchronous event system the only solution?

Comment: While I feel that it is probably possible to simplify this design somehow, I don't know enough about the system you are building, so I won't go into that; regarding the specific issue you asked about, you could modify the constructor of `ConnectedStateNavigator` and replace the `viewFactory` parameter with a lambda that takes in a navigator, calls the constructor, and returns an instance of the factory (`Function<ConnectedStateNavigator,ConnectedStateViewFactory> factoryCreator`). You'd then just do `viewFactory = factoryCreator.apply(this)` in the body.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Hmm, I understand what you mean but isn't this just a fancier version of a setter? I have seen it used in other projects but I am not sure of what this acomplishes

Comment: With a setter, you remove the dependency from the constructor of the view factory (so it becomes less explicit); then, when the object is instantiated, it's not in a usable state until you pass the dependency to the setter. A lambda here essentially acts as a single-method factory for the viewFactory, and returns a ready-to-use, complete object; it's essentially breaking the circular dependency of the constructors (in the context of object creation). But again, maybe a better way to go about it is to reexamine the problem, find some new point of view, and redesign things.